# Is it possible to get_the_post_thumbnail (Featured Image) inside a sprintf function?

Tags: menus, post-thumbnails, navigation, walker

I am trying to add the featured image of posts to my mega menu. I want to display the featured image inside a div tag. How would i add the featured image inside of a sprintf function?

```
$thumbnail = '';
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $item->object_id ) ) {
  $thumbnail = the_post_thumbnail_url( $item->object_id );
  }


class Walker_Nav_Primary extends Walker_Nav_menu {
    
    


    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        if ( array_search( 'menu-item-has-children', $item->classes )&& $depth==0 ) {
            $output .= sprintf( "\n<li class='topnavitem %s'><a href='%s' class=\"topnavtext\">%s</a>\n", ( array_search( 'current-menu-item', $item->classes ) || array_search( 'current-page-parent', $item->classes ) ) ? '' : '', $item->url, $item->title );
        } 
        
        elseif ( array_search( 'menu-item-has-children', $item->classes )&& $depth==1 ) {
            $output .= sprintf( "\n<li class='productsnav %s'><a href='%s' class=\"productsnavtext\">%s</a>\n", ( array_search( 'current-menu-item', $item->classes ) || array_search( 'current-page-parent', $item->classes ) ) ? '' : '', $item->url, $item->title );
        } 
        
        
        
        elseif ($depth==2){
            $output .= sprintf( "\n<li class='secondnavitem %s'>
            
            <div class='pictext'> \\I want the featured image here
            
               <a href='%s' class=\"secondnavtext\">%s</a>\n", ( array_search( 'current-menu-item', $item->classes) ) ? '' : '', $item->url, $item->title );
        }
        
        
        
        
        else {
            $output .= sprintf( "\n<li class='topnavitem %s'><a href='%s' class=\"topnavtext\">%s</a>\n", ( array_search( 'current-menu-item', $item->classes) ) ? '' : '', $item->url, $item->title );
        }
    }

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth ) {
        $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
        if ($depth == 0) {
$output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"nav-level-one\" role=\"submenu\">\n";
}


if ($depth == 1) {
$output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"nav-level-two\" role=\"subsubmenu\">\n";
}
        
        
        
  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I missed something that's more complex in your question, but sprintf should not be an issue with an img tag. If you want to specify the value as string you can use the %s handler.

```php
sprintf('<div>...<img src="%s" />...</div>', $thumbnail);
```

Comment: Thanks, but its showing the img src as unknown. Is there something wrong with the $thumbnail variable itself?

Comment: Most likely yes, your code did not explain how you were getting the $thumbnail from inside the Walker. Please add your latest code you're working on so I can see how you're getting the thumbnail url.

Comment: Here you go, i'm only posting the relevant section because of the character limit: `Function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ){
$thumbnail = the_post_thumbnail_url( $item->object_id);         elseif ($depth==2){
            $output .= sprintf( "\n<li class='navtwoitem %s'><div class='pictext'><img src='%s' /><a href='%s' class=\"navtwotext\">%s</a></div>\n", ( array_search( 'current-menu-item', $item->classes) ) ? '' : '', $thumbnail,$item->url, $item->title );
        }`

Comment: I don't think `$item->object_id` is the post id, rather the menu id iirc. My guess is that' the issue. You'll need a way to retrieve the post id from the menu item. You could do it by url or add a custom meta field on each menu item and then reference that. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks a ton Phil. I used the url_to_postid(); function and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help.